# How can I get rid of all script blocks in html files?

Tags: shell-script, sed

How can I remove all script blocks (including multi-line ones) from html files such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>
```

I tried things like this with no success:

```
sed -i -e 's/<script.*\n.*<\/script>//g' 'path/to/file.html'
```

Comment: @mikeserv the answer on the dupe works perfectly for the OP's example here. I have no idea what `..."...span>"...` is supposed to be. In any case, this question has already been answered to the OP's satisfaction so, again, there's no point in having them both open. However, there are mechanisms in place for cases where you feel a question has been wrongly closed: i) vote to reopen and ii) bring it up on [meta].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sed` you can select ranges and delete them:

```
sed '/<script/,/<\/script>/d' inputfile
```

Comment: This would delete everything before `<script` on the same line, and similarly for the other end.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yours looks better than the answer in the question that caused this to be marked as "duplicate". I suggest a minor addition: `sed '/<script/,/<\/script>/d' inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: @choroba : THX! It does indeed. So one needs to enclose the range with `^` and `$` or better still insert new line before and after when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Not correct: sed is greedy.

Answer (score 7):

Sed processes the input line by line. It's easier in Perl that can process the whole file at once:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's=<script>.*?\n.*?</script>==sg'
```

- `-0777` reads the whole file
- `?` after `*` makes it "frugal", i.e. it matches the shortest possible string.
- `/s` makes `.` match a newline which it normally doesn't.

Note that it can break if the script contains `</script>` in a comment or quotes. It would be better to parse the HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually the answer in the question that caused this to be marked as "duplicate" seems to do the job perfectly:  `perl -0777 -pe 's/<script.*?script>//gs' example.html`

Comment: @Sadi: It removes single line scripts, too.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I should have made it clearer...